# Django ORM fetching

Tags: django, django-models, orm

i want to fetch data from Django model using Q().

what i want is

```
obj = models.Products.objects(Q(description=[a list of descriptions]))
```

I want all the objects matching the descriptions with the elements of the list

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**`__in`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
obj = models.Products.objects.filter(description__in=[a list of descriptions])
```

That being said, often using such queries actually aims to solve another more fundamental problem. It might be better to look *why* you think you need to filter on a list of descriptions, since that is often *not* necessary.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Product` instead of <s>`Products`</s>.